# VueJS emit to component works but with error Cannot read apply property

Tags: vue.js, events

I have a component structure like this:

```
/parent
  /childA
  /childB
```

I would like to send a message from `childA` to `childB`, so in `childA` VueJS component, I am emitting an event like this:

```
this.$root.$emit('message', 'hello')
```

In `childB` component, I am registering a listener like this:

```
  mounted() {
    this.$root.$on('message', (arg) => {
      console.log('message: '+arg)
    })
  }
```

When the event is fired (upon a user interaction) in `childA` I see this in the console:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in event handler for "message": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined"

TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

message: 
(3) message: hello
```

The `(3)` is the number `3` appearing in a circle, indicating (I believe) that the same `console.log` has occurred 3 times.

Why are these errors occurring when the event clearing succeeds?

If it helps, I got my code from [this Medium post](https://medium.com/js-dojo/component-communication-in-vue-js-ca8b591d7efa).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

For emit in your component:

```
this.$emit('message', 'hello')
```

And in your parent component you don't need to create a listener at 'mounted()'. just in your template section, call a method on that event like this:

```
<component @message="showMessage"/>
```

Then create a method like this:

```
methods: {
  showMessage (message) {
    console.log(message)
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not listening on the parent or child component. These are two separate components. They are both in the same parent component, but they are not in a parent/child relationship/structure.

Comment: I have updated my post to describe the structure of the components a bit more.

Comment: In this case you need to use a EventBus.
With EventBus you can raise an event anywhere and handle it anywhere.

View this article to find out how to use an EventBus:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-global-event-bus

Comment: This is not working in my case. I have the event being fired from within an axios handler.