# Axios event handler unable to fire event on EventBux

Tags: vue.js, axios, event-handling

I have the following code in my VueJS component A:

```
<script>
import EventBus from '@/event-bus.js'

export default {
  name: 'ProductSearch',
  methods: {
    getMaterials(materialNum) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.$axios.get('url')
          .then((response) => { ... })
          .catch((error) => { ...  })
          .then(() => {
            // always executed
            // this.$root.$emit('message', 'hello')
            EventBus.$emit('message', 'hello')
          })
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Because `this.$root.$emit('message', 'hello')` did not work, I have utilised `EventBus` ([after reading this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66511043/vuejs-emit-to-component-works-but-with-error-cannot-read-apply-property/66513654#66513654))

I another component, I have this code:

```
<script>
import EventBus from '@/event-bus.js'

export default {
  name: 'CountrySelect',
  mounted() {
    EventBus.$on('message', showMessage)
  },
  methods: {
    showMessage(message) {
      console.log(message)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

However, this does not work and fails on page load with the following error:

```
[Vue warn] Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property '$on' of undefined"
```

How can I set inter-component events without utilising the parent and have this work from within axuios event handlers?